# Dynamically generate input type="file" elements for multiple uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem that i tried solve myself. But i didn't. I'm creating a script that can upload multiple pictures by one time. I get one input file field as the first time and i've wrote a JavaScript if someone has added a photo for upload field, then generate new upload field automatically. It's working well for the first time. It was successful generate new upload field. But It hasn't generate for second time. I assume that you have a knowledge about bootstrap.

here is my HTML code

```
 <input type ="file" class ="fileup 1" id ="file1">
 <label for ="file1" id ="lbl_upload">
 <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></label>
 <div class ="photos"> </div>
```

here my JavaScript code

```
var count = 1;
$("#file1" + count).on('change', '.fileup', function() {
    var files, imagetype, matches;
    files = this.files[0];
    imagetype = files.type;
    matches = ["image/jpeg"];
    var str = "#img_nxt" + count;
    if (!(imagetype == matches[0])) {
        alert("Wrong format");
    } else {
        $('#lbl_upload').remove();
        $('.photos').append("<img id='img_nxt" + count + "' width ='100' height ='100'> ");
        //create a new input file element 
        count++;
        $('.photos').append("<input type =\"file\" class =\"fileup " + count + "\" id =\"file" + count + "\"><label for =\"file" + count + "\" id =\"lbl_upload\"><span class =\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign\"></span></label>");
        //show picture in image element
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $(str).attr("src", e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(files);
        return true;
    }
});
```

here is my CSS

```
[class*="fileup"]{
position:fixed;
top:5000px;
}
```

Where i went wrong? Thank you dedicating your time for make a solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically. Since you have already using a common class  `fileup` with `file` input control. *Change your code as*,

```
$('.photos').on('change', '.fileup', function() {
    //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because click event is not associated with dynamically added element. You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in this case.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Also as IDs are generated dynamically with a fixed start with pattern, you can use attribute start with selector while binding the event using event delegation:

```
$('.photos').on('change','[id^=file]',function(){
```